# Insert Groups of Rows with PHP & MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to load data from a few hundred text files into a database.

I believe MYSQL is exiting out of the loop without inserting all the rows.

Can anyone suggest how to insert blocks of 1000 rows to the end of data, with PHP code?

```
$filenames_array = array();

foreach($filenames_array as $filename)
{

        $file_array     = file($filename);
        $file_value     = $file_array[0];
        $new_array  = explode(",", $file_value);
        $length         = count($new_array);


        for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++)
        {

        $sql = "INSERT INTO `names`
            (`id`, `name`)   

            VALUES 
            ('',
            '" . $new_array[$i] . "'
            )";

        $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
        echo $i . 'Row Inserted<br />';
        }

    }
```

Comment: Where is $filenames_array being initialized? Which loop is terminating early? The for-loop? Why are you sure that the for-loop is terminating early? When it terminates, does the die(mysql_error()); statement give you any output? If so, why? What do you mean "blocks of 1000 rows to the end of data"? Do you mean adding 1000 entries to an existing MySQL table at a time?

Comment: I didn't take the time to type out the filename array. It's an array of all the filenames. I think the problem lies with mysql. The reason I say this is because an export of SQL with phpmyadmin breaks up inserts into blocks of 1500 rows. I'm asking to do something similar.

Answer (score 0):

you're probably trying to run too many INSERT statements in a single query.

look into [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) and prepared statements or use SQL syntax like this:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9);
```

Comment: if he's dealing with a few hundred text files, I don't think the multiple insert syntax would be a viable solution?

Comment: he's not really sending out many inserts in a single query - always just one at a time

Comment: Inserting multiple rows with one query is faster than with multiple queries so if his script times out rewriting it to insert 1000 rows in one query might help.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that one of the entries you're trying to insert contains a single quote '? In this case, an error would occur and the the loop wouldn't finish.

You should always escape the values you insert into the database with mysql_real_escape_string to prevent problems like that, and to make sure you're not vulnerable to [sql injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Injection).

```
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `names`
            (`id`, `name`)   

            VALUES 
            ('',
            '" . mysql_real_escape_string($new_array[$i]) . "'
            )";
```

Comment: The data does not contain single quotes. I think this is a MYSQL issue.

Answer (score 0):

Why not combine every txt file into one big text file, and read it line by line? See the examples here http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php

Mainly:

```
<?php
$handle = @fopen("/tmp/inputfile.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (!feof($handle)) {
        $buffer = fgets($handle, 4096);
        echo $buffer;
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

Comment: I have several hundred textfiles. Copy and Pasting all the information defeats the purpose of writing this code. MYSQL exits after around 1100 row inserts also. I need to insert around 6000 rows.

Comment: By combining everything into a text file, I didn't mean copy and paste. Maybe you could read a list of all files into an array, copy the contents of each one using file_get_contents and file_put_contents, and have it all done automatically! :)